# as don't understand 'm' flag

Tags: ios, gnu, assembly

I'm trying to create o-file from asm file by this command:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/as -mcpu=arm -o /Users/vladimirvlasov/Projects/Test/TestLib/bin/Debug/TestLib.dll.o /var/folders/gr/dd5_js7106n8jyg3chy2cnf40000gn/T/mono_aot_wmZyE9
```

But I get error:

```
FATAL:/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!
```

Standard **as** (not from iOS SDK) prints the same error.

Please, help. Say, what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the `-arch arm` flag not `-mcpu=arm`